# Extended object not persisting in database

Tags: java, database, inheritance, persistence, entity

I have two classes: `Furniture` and `Painting`. Those are extending `Item`.

Item has the following code:

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Comparable, Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne 
    private User seller;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
     @AttributeOverride(name = "description",
        column = @Column(name = "c_description"))})
    private Category category;
    private String description;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(User seller, Category category, String description) {
        this.seller = seller;
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
        this.seller.addItem(this);
    }
```

Painting has the following code:

```
@Entity
public class Painting extends Item {

    private String title;
    private String painter;

    public Painting() {

    }

    public Painting(String title, String painter, User seller, Category category, String description) {
        super(seller, category, description);
        this.title = title;
        this.painter = painter;
    }
```

Furniture has the following code:

```
@Entity
public class Furniture extends Item {

    private String material;

    public Furniture() {

    }

    public Furniture(String material, User seller, Category category, String description) {
        super(seller, category, description);
        this.material = material;
    }
```

Before, I tried some code persisting the `Item` objects. That worked fine. 
Now I'm trying to persist a `Painting`-object, persisting it through an Entity Manager. 
I get the following error:

> Object: auction.domain.Furniture@5d3468fd is not a known entity type.

It seems like I forgot something or did something wrong, probably in the `Painting`-class. What could it be?

Comment: how did you map your table with entity class ? eclipse link I use with @Table annotation

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that. This is all the code I have relative for this question, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update my Persistence Unit. After adding the `Furniture` and `Painting` classes, the information got in to the database. Above code is correct.